# Unable to make Rest API Call using proxy in angular 2

Tags: angular, proxy

I am using wepack.dev.js and wanted to create a proxy for my backend services.

In my webpack-dev

```
 proxy: {

 "/api/2/": {
        target: 'http://localhost:8080',
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        logLevel: 'debug',
        agent: process.env.HTTP_PROXY ? new HttpsProxyAgent(process.env.HTTP_PROXY) : undefined,
        headers: {
          "x-api-token": "122",
          "Authorization": "Basic 1122222="
        }
      },

}
```

> I have tried to put ** also like /api/2/**. But, its not working.

On the console while doing npm start I can see the meesage of proxy being created but, when I am hitting the URL I am getting

> net::ERR_UNEXPECTED_PROXY_AUTH

Can anybody suggest what is missing?

Comment: have you tried keeping that config at the bare minimum with only the `target` property? Also you may consider to add `pathRewrite: {"^/api" : ""}`

Comment: @crash yes i tried with that also. The same configuration is working for my production URL but for local its not working.

Comment: maybe the `agent` returning `undefined` or an incorrect `Authorization` header/token?

Comment: @crash this is the response i am getting back {"_body":{"isTrusted":true},"status":0,"ok":false,"statusText":"","headers":{},"type":3,"url":null}

Comment: the response from what? Did you change anything? Can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: @crash when i am hitting the rest api for which the proxy is configured . I am getting the above response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147779/discussion-between-crash-and-rohitesh).